Squiggly line overlapping text on VS Code 1.88
Recently my VS Code started to place the squiggly line overlapping the text. I've searched everywhere but got no answer why this is happening... Does anyone have a clue?


what does it say when you hover over it?

It shows the documentation of what you are hovering.

what's  your editor font setting set to?

Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. If you haven't modified your font setting, I'd suggest raising an issue ticket to at least make maintainers aware of this. if you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket.

This issue is also reported after the recent VS Code version: Code 1.88.0 update - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/209614 Please consider leaving a comment there also to share your inputs.

Update: it was fixed, see PR.  Should be in vscode 1.89 Stable early May, 2024.

It seems to be theme-dependent.  See GitHub: Squiggly lines have moved slightly upwards after the update.
So changing to another theme might fix it before it is corrected.
And it has been reported that downgrading vscode to v1.87 fixed it too.
Or try creating these colorCustomization in your settings.json:
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    "editorError.border": "#f009",  // an error border with some opacity
    "editorError.foreground": "#0000",  // set the squiggly to transparent
}

It seems to help.
Or there are a couple of suggestions at https://github.com/wesbos/cobalt2-vscode/issues/248#issuecomment-2042204084 but I don't like them.
